# How to create multi level menu using Yii

Tags: php, html, yii, dao

How do I do a query to the case of multi-level menus in yii?

For example I have a table like this :

[image]

`menu_name` will follow `parrent_id` it has, so it will form a hierarchical menu

[image]

How do I use `Yii DAO` on my layout so that the output as html above

My Code :

```
<?php
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CMenu', true);

class ActiveMenu extends CMenu
{
    public function init(){

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition='published=:idpub AND menu_controller=:menu';
    $criteria->params=array(':idpub'=>1, ':menu'=>'#');

    $items = Menu::model()->findAll($criteria);

    echo "<ul id='yw1' class='nav'>";

        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            echo "<li class='dropdown'>
                    <a href=".$item->menu_controller." data-toggle='dropdown' class='dropdown-toggle'>
                    <i class='icon-white icon-list'></i>".$item->menu_name."<b class='caret'></b></a>
                </li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

But in the above code I only get `parents data`. How do I want to loop to get the `childs data` include in every parents menu like this html code :

```
<ul id="yw1" class="nav">
    <li><a href="/app/home.html"><span class="icon-white icon-tasks"></span> Home</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="icon-white icon-list"></i>Master<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="expedition"><span class="icon-bar icon-list"></span> Expedition</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="partner"><span class="icon-bar icon-list"></span> Partner</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="user"><span class="icon-bar icon-list"></span> User</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="icon-white icon-list"></i>Transaction<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="processin"><span class="icon-bar icon-list"></span> Process In</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="processout"><span class="icon-bar icon-list"></span> Process Out</a></li>
        </ul>
        etc ....
        etc ....
        etc ....
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first have the relations set up properly in your `Menu` model (Menu.php).

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Menu', 'parent_id'),
            'children' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Menu', 'parent_id'),
        );
    }
```

And then modify the codes:

```
  //other codes

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    echo "<li class='dropdown'>
    <a href=".$item->menu_controller." data-toggle='dropdown' class='dropdown-toggle'>
    <i class='icon-white icon-list'></i>".$item->menu_name."<b class='caret'></b></a>
    </li>";
    foreach ($item->children as $child) {
        echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href='".$child->menu_controller."'><span class='icon-bar icon-list'></span> ".$child->menu_name."</a></li></u>";
    }
}

  //other codes
```